# How to get a list of Job Batches in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, queue, jobs, batching, job-batching

Laravel 8 introduced [Job Batching](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#job-batching), which allows to execute jobs in batches and perform actions on batch completion.
The feature itself seems very useful, and it even has an `Illuminate\Bus\Batch` instance, which allows to inspect and interact with the Jobs Batch.

There seems to be a method to fetch a single Batch by id `Bus::findBatch($batchId);`, but unfortunately I couldn't find a method to fetch a collection of Batches.
Is it possible to fetch multiple Jobs Batches, or the only way is to separately call `Bus::findBatch($batchId);` for each `$batchId` in `job_batches` table?

Answer (score 1):

I took a look at the implementation of laravel horizon. It seems that they are creating a service provider which than registers the commands and services used by the horizon panel. If that service provider is booted (meaning you have horizon installed) an instance of [BatchRepository](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Bus/BatchRepository.html) can be catched in any controller constructor or method. The BatchRepository-object than offers a get method for retrieving the list of batches in database.

[image]
[image]
Should be possible to retrieve the lists by using the horizon-api-routes also.
See:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this! super eazy

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

   public function getAllBatches()
{
    return DB::table('job_batches')->get();
}
```